# EntryPointNotFoundException With Unity Plugin

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, dll, runtime-error

I'm very new to writing c++ plugins for unity but must do so now. I have been loosely following [this](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-native-plugins-2019-3#60149f92edbc2a0f1dcfdceb) tutorial and created the following in a visual studio dll project uncreatively called UnityPluginTest:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DLLExport __declspec (dllexport)

extern "C"
{
    DLLExport int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(0));
        return (rand() % (max - min) + min);
    }
}
```

I created a completely new unity project to test it (Unity 2020.2.f1 if it matters), and copied the compiled .dll file into a new folder Assets/Plugins. I then made a new script called (equally uncreatively) TestFirstUnityPluginTest.cs which contains the following:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestFirstUnityPluginTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    const string dll = "__Internal";

    [DllImport(dll)]
    private static extern int RandomNumber(int min, int max);

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(RandomNumber(0, 10));
    }
}
```

When I put the script on a gameobject and hit play, I get an error stating "EntryPointNotFoundException: RandomNumber" with a stack trace pointing to the Debug.Log() call. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This might solve your problem. [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/what-can-i-do-with-this-entrypointnotfoundexception.144276/).

Comment: I have seen several similar answers, but they mostly seem to relate to .dll files which reference or depend on other .dll files. That is not the case in this situation as far as I can tell. The dll I am creating has no such dependencies, and I've tried putting my copied .dll file in both Assets/Plugins and in the root directory for the unity project, so I don't think it's an issue of where the .dll file is placed.

Comment: __Internal is only for IOS so check that out.

Comment: I did try using the name of the plugin instead of __Internal, however it seemed to not find the plugin at all in that case. It seems with this error, it is finding the plugin, just failing to figure out where to read the correct function if I am understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify entry point and use DECORATED name:

replace [DllImport(dll)] by [DllImport("YOUR_DLL_NAME.dll", EntryPoint = "DecoratedFunctionName")]

My C++ code:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int Double(int number)
{
    return number * 2;
}
```

My Unity3d C# code:

```
[DllImport("Dll4_CPP.dll", EntryPoint = "?Double@@YAHH@Z")]
public static extern int Double(int number);
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log(Double(10));
}
```

Decorated name - name of the function inside DLL (compiler renames it).
[Dumpbin.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-160) helps to find it:
VisualStudion2019 -> Tools -> CommandLine -> DeveloperComandPrompt

```
cd <your PathToDLL>
dumpbin /exports Dll4_CPP.dll
```

it will print:

```
...
1    0 00011217 ?Double@@YAHH@Z = @ILT+530(?Double@@YAHH@Z)
...
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.entrypointnotfoundexception?view=net-5.0)